# What is a collection or a great number of baskets called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terms-of-venery

Let's say you have some baskets of cherries, blueberries... whatever.

1. Is there a name for an aggregate? As in a *flock* of birds, a *scurry* of squirrels, etc..
2. Is there a name for a specific number or amount of baskets? E.g.:

- A *cord* of wood is a pile 8x4x4ft
- A *perch* of stone is a pile 16.5x1.5x1ft
- A *?* of baskets is a collection ...

Any English word to describe this? tyvm Keith :^)

Comment: I think we need to know why you wish to refer to the collection. There may not be a collective noun just for baskets but there may be an appropriate term you could use but it depends on the purpose.  “We have a wide assortment of baskets” “We have a nice collection of baskets” “We have a nice selection of baskets” “We have a wide array of baskets” “We have a large display of baskets”  More metaphorical: “The table was covered in a blanket of baskets”  The room was awash in a sea of baskets

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to baskets, but generally applicable to any manufactured item (often used in a production context), one option is **Batch**:

> a group of things or people dealt with at the same time or considered similar in type:
> *The cook brought in a fresh batch of homemade cupcakes.
> We looked at the job applications in two batches.* ([Cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/batch))

From the same context, but also generally applicable: **Lot**:

> an amount or set of things, especially when there are several of these amounts:
> *I've already done one lot of washing.
> Another lot of visitors will be here this afternoon.* ([Cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lot))

Both of them are used to reference a particular "set" of items that were manufactured or processed at the same time or in the same location, to distinguish them from other similar (not to say apparently identical) sets:

> Batch number is also referred to as “lot number”. Recording of the batch and batch number typically starts at the manufacturing plant. Batches should be maintained and recorded according to:
>
> - Quantity
> - Manufacturing cycle
> - Expiry date
> - Weight of the active ingredient
> - Excipient(s)
>   ([lfatabletpresses.com](https://www.lfatabletpresses.com/articles/why-batch-produce-use-batch-numbers))

Here is an example in the wild (no commercial ties!):

> Fresh batch of baskets have arrived in a variety of colors and sizes Open today 11-7 ([facebook.com](https://es-la.facebook.com/shopursa/photos/fresh-batch-of-baskets-have-arrived-in-a-variety-of-colors-and-sizes-open-today-/1892494634385211/))

Comment: OP specifies a collective noun specific to baskets: 'as in a flock of birds, a scurry of squirrels ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, they're not exclusive. These are _used_ for baskets, though, so it's fair game. Cheers!

Comment: And for a specific number, 'dozen'?

Comment: @Edwin Ah, there you finished this answer off... I understand now, I think. The best I can think of for that is just _dozen_! Anyhow, I'll let it soak for now, and I might come back and delete this later. Cheers!

Comment: OP wants a _specific kind_ of regular "collective noun", no?

Comment: @Conrado Although it's not specific to baskets, and is also not a collective noun, you could use **count**. Tying this into the existing answer, it would be a ***batch count*** *of baskets*.

Comment: The problem is that collective nouns depend on context. A skein of geese is not the same as a gaggle of geese, which differs from a flock; a parliament of owls is not the same as a flock of owls, etc. To that extent, a batch of "x" will be correct in one context, but not another. (Another thought: collective nouns - other than ubiquitous "set", etc - usually apply to animate objects.)